# file object showing garbage value using cin cout?

Tags: c++, file, cin, cout, turbo-c++

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fstream.h>

void main()
{
    int i, j, k;

    clrscr();

    ofstream out("INT.TST");
    ifstream in("INT.TST");

    out << 25 << ' ' << 4567 << ' ' << 8910;

    in >> i >> j >> k;
    cout << i << ' ' << j << ' ' << k;
    getch();
}
```

the output of this program should be :

```
25 567 8910
```

but it is show in this :

```
8370 0 1530
```

why it is showing garbage value ?

Comment: You never flushed the output to the file.

Comment: i did "out.flush();" after the 11th line . now it is showing this output:: 8378 0 1530

Comment: please help how can i get the proper answer?

Comment: Open the file for input after doing the `flush()`

Comment: not working after doing this-- "open the file for input after doing flush()"

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you are claiming: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8cc80845a5d9616

Comment: You forgot to check that your inputs succeeded, and to initialise your variables.

Comment: Try initializing i, j, and k to 0 or some other value. If those values are printed it means that the reading failed. Right now you could just be printing the contents of some uninitialized memory which is why you are getting such strange numbers.

Comment: "`#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fstream.h>`" - You should get yourself a more modern compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Your code could choke on a recent (decent?) compiler, because you are opening same file twice, once for reading and once for writing. This is normally not allowed on Windows, unless you pass special values to the underlying WinAPI call. As Turbo-C++ is deprecated for decades, I am not sure whether it throws exceptions when it cannot open a file or simply gives you a closed stream. So you should always control input functions!

A more or less fixed version of your code could be:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>           // avoid if you can: non portable
#include<fstream.h>

int main()                  // NEVER use void main!
{
    int i, j, k;

    clrscr();               // avoid if you can: non portable

    ofstream out("INT.TST");
    out << 25 << ' ' << 4567 << ' ' << 8910;
    out.close()             // Ok, file is now closed

    ifstream in("INT.TST");
    in >> i >> j >> k;

    if (! in) {
        cerr << "Error reading file\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << i << ' ' << j << ' ' << k;
    }
    getch();              // avoid if you can: non portable
    return 0;             // not strictly necessary but IMHO cleaner
}
```

Comment: `void main()` is also non portable.

Answer (score 0):

I tested a code similar yours in gcc and msvc and it worked as you expected in Ubuntu or Windows. I believe that you don't have permission to create or open file (like online compilers such as [ideone.com](http://ideone.com)). Because you have not checked if file is opened (with `is_open()`), you may be using with a closed file and unpredictable results. See following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, j, k;

    ofstream out("INT.TST");
    ifstream in("INT.TST");

    out << 25 << ' ' << 4567 << ' ' << 8910;

    out.flush();

    if (!in.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Error opening file";
    }
    else
    {
        in >> i >> j >> k;
        cout << i << ' ' << j << ' ' << k;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It writes `Error opening file` in ideone but it works on Ubuntu and Windows as you expected.